# Pythonic way to check if x is a module

Tags: python, syntax

This works for builtin types (str, list, int, etc) and for classes that are imported properly, but not module:

```
type(x) is module #NameError: name 'module' is not defined.
```

There are workarounds:

```
str(type(x)) == "<class 'module'>"
type(x) is type(os) # Or any imported module object.
```

But is there a more *pythonic* way?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ModuleType

Comment: If you don't already know whether `x` is a module, why will it help you solve a problem to find out? And how did you get into this position in the first place? If you didn't `import x` yourself, then presumably it comes from some other piece of the code *which is explicitly trying to take advantage of duck typing*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: It's useful when you are writing analysis tools  that i.e. need to know all non-module attributes of a module. It isn't generally used in the python code itself as you would just "import foo" to use the module foo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `inspect` module, or you can use `isinstance` with the appropriate type.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import types
>>> inspect.ismodule(inspect)
True
>>> isinstance(inspect, types.ModuleType)
True
```